# Div Ontop of Div Without Effecting Top Margin?

Tags: html, css

How do I position a div from the top of page without effecting the position of the div below it? i.e. I have a nav div that runs along the top of my page (margin 0px from top). I also have a wrapper div below it positioned 100px from top. If I decide to move the nav div 10px from the top, it will push the wrapper div to 110px from top. I don't want this to happen. I don't want to use absolute positioning.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
height: 69px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#wrapper {
height: 775px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about relative positioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#nav {
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Then you have something in your HTML/CSS that causes that. Any more code? Or a link we can look at?

Comment: Yes, it does! <style type="text/css">
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#nav {
 background-color: #F00;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
 background-color: #00F;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>

Comment: I want to be able to control the top margin of the second from the top of the page, not from the bottom of the first div. Isn't there some way for the second div to ignore the first div position and treat it like it isn't there?

Comment: You have to drop `margin-top` on `#nav` and add the `top:10px` like in my answer

Comment: ok but as soon as I put an image inside of the nav div and try to position the image within the div from the top, it goes back to effecting the second div again.

Comment: Never mind. I worked it out. I needed to float the image left within the div. Thanks!

Comment: look here (http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) how to use css position

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative margin on the wrapper div equal to what you put on the nav div.

```
#wrapper { margin-top: -10px; }
```

Comment: The whole point to the post was without effecting the div below. Not compensating.